# How to draw a curved line in Box2d?

Tags: java, box2d

I need to draw a curved line, I have searched the Internet but found nothing that would suit my needs.

I used `b2ChainShape` but it's not completely what I need.

How can I draw a curved line with Box2d?

Answer (score 1):

You should use b2EdgeShape.

I used [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32958/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-2) to achieve a curved collisioning line in Box2D Cocos2dX (the tutorial is in ObjectiveC - C++, but it will give you the idea).

But at the end, it's making little rects making a bigger line that simulates a curved line:

```
b2BodyDef bd;
bd.position.Set(0, 0);

m_body = m_world->CreateBody(&bd);

b2EdgeShape shape;

b2Vec2 p1, p2;
for (int i=0; i<m_nBorderVertices-1; i++) {
    p1 = b2Vec2(((m_borderVertices[i].x  - winSize.width/2)/PTM_RATIO), ((m_borderVertices[i].y - winSize.height/2)/PTM_RATIO));
    p2 = b2Vec2(((m_borderVertices[i+1].x - winSize.width/2)/PTM_RATIO) ,((m_borderVertices[i+1].y - winSize.height/2)/PTM_RATIO));
    shape.Set(p1, p2);
    m_body->CreateFixture(&shape, 0);
}
```

Comment: i'm tryng all day to implement it , but no luck ....

Comment: Have you filled m_borderVertices with a lot of points (or Vec2, ccp...) simulating a rounded hill? Check out the method `-(void)resetHillVertices` in this tutorial: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32954/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-1)